# GenericDialogPlus - saving FileField as a new variable?

Tags: python, dialog, jython, imagej, fiji

Newbie to scripting here.

I’d like to create a dialog window that prompts user to choose 2 files (“pos”, and “neg”). I’d also like to store these file paths as a variable to use later on.

I’m having trouble storing the file paths. Instead of storing the user chosen paths, I am only able to collect the default path.

```
import os 
from java.io import File 
from ij import IJ 
from ij.gui import GenericDialog 
from fiji.util.gui import GenericDialogPlus
> 
gdp = GenericDialogPlus(“test”) 
gdp.addFileField(“pos”, “C:/Users/”)
pos = gdp.getNextString() 
gdp.addFileField(“neg”, “C:/Users/”) 
neg = gdp.getNextString() 
gdp.showDialog() 
print("yourfiles "+ pos+ " " + neg)
```

But this just reutrns:

> yourfiles C:/Users/ C:/Users/

even if the user has selected a new file, ie: `C:/Users/test.tiff`

I’d like the output to be based on whatever the user chose:

> yourfiles C:/Users/test.tiff C:/Users/negative.tiff

What command am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: This question was [cross-posted to the ImageJ forum](http://forum.imagej.net/t/genericdialogplus-storing-addfilefield-as-variable/10209?u=imagejan) and received an accepted answer there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Advice from the x-post on ImageJ forum led me the solution.
Variable asignment based on user input needs to be done after the dialog box is shown (*duh*, after user input...)

```
    import os 
    from java.io import File 
    from ij import IJ 
    from ij.gui import GenericDialog 
    from fiji.util.gui import GenericDialogPlus

    gdp = GenericDialogPlus(“test”) 
    gdp.addFileField(“pos”, “C:/Users/”)
    gdp.addFileField(“neg”, “C:/Users/”) 
    gdp.showDialog()

    pos = gdp.getNextString()
    neg = gdp.getNextString()
    print("yourfiles "+ pos+ " " + neg)
```

output:

> yourfiles C:/Users/test.tiff C:/Users/negative.tiff

Answer (score 2):

I would go for the parameter annotations of scijava. They also work in scripts: https://imagej.net/Script_Parameters

Bellow you find a python example example:

```
# @File(label='input directory', style='directory') indir
# @File(label='input file') infile

print 'input directory' + indir.getAbsolutePath()
print 'input file' + infile.getAbsolutePath()
```

...easier to handle and more elegant.